# When a bittorrent client program "rechecks" a torrent, what does it really do?

Tags: home-networking, bittorrent

Had a power outage while downloading, resulting in I/O buffer errors (computer on UPS, while external HDD was not).

If there were any data errors, will the "rechecking" process detect these and revert these chunks to an "undownloaded" state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a torrent is rechecked, the client reads the torrent's data and computes block hashes which it compares with the block hashes in the `.torrent` file, if the hash matches the block is done, otherwise if it is not, it is marked for retrieval. Then the client can start downloading the torrent from peers requesting the blocks which are needed.

Commonly torrent clients cache these marks so that the torrent can be paused and resumed without needing to check blocks but if the torrent client doesn't exit correctly or can't save the list of done blocks, that list must be rebuild and that is what happens when a torrent client rechecks.